# Textures appears white in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-opengl

I can't load a `BMP texture` and show it on faces of a cube.
I am working on `Windows 7`.My compiler is `Visual Studio 2010 Express`.I use `FreeImage` to load the bmp.My image bit depth is 24.My image size is 256 * 256.I am using `SDL` to create window and handle the events.
When I compile and run the program my cube is still white and nothing is shown on its faces.I am loading the texture into a `GLuint` variable.When I print that variable it only prints "1". One of my friends told me that my graphic card is incompatible with this version of `OpenGL`.So I compiled and ran the program in an `Ubuntu` on a virtual machine and it worked fine.The cube was textured successfully.Can you please help me to run it on my `Windows` propely?
And if you need my graphic card is `NVIDIA GT240 DDR5`.

## EDIT

This is my initgl function:

```
//OpenGL initialization.
int initGL(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable texture mapping.
    if(!loadGLTextures("bmp_24.bmp"))
        return false;

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    //Nice perspective.
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT , GL_NICEST);
    return true;
}
```

And this is the function that loads the image.GLuint texture[1] has been defined before:

```
//This function will load a bitmap image.
bool loadGLTextures(const char* file)
{
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;

    fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(file , 0);
    if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
        fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(file);
    if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
        return false;

    FIBITMAP* dib = FreeImage_Load(fif , file);

    if(!dib)
        return false;
    
    //Create the texture.
    glGenTextures(1 , &texture[0]);

    //Typical texture generation using data from the bitmap.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , texture[0]);

    //Generate the texture.
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_RGB , FreeImage_GetWidth(dib) , 
        FreeImage_GetHeight(dib) , 0 , GL_BGR_EXT , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , 
        FreeImage_GetBits(dib));



    //Linear filtering.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR);

    printf("%d" , texture[0]);

    FreeImage_Unload(dib);

    return true;

}
```

And this is my render function:

```
//All of the drawing goes through this.
int drawGLScene(void)
{
    static float xrot = 0 , yrot = 0 , zrot = 0;
    //Clear screen and depth buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0f , 0.0f , -5.0f);
    glRotatef(xrot , 1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yrot , 0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f);
    glRotatef(zrot , 0.0f , 0.0f  ,1.0f);

    //Select the texture.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , texture[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //Front:
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Bottom right fo the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Top right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Top left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);

    //Back:
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Bottom right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top right of the texture and the quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top left of the texture and the quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);

    //Top:
    //Top right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Bottom right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);

    //Bottom:
    //Top left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Bottom right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);

    //Right:
    //Bottom right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Top left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);

    //Left:
    //Bottom left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , -1.0f);
    //Bottom right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , -1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Top right of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);
    //Top left of the texture and quad.
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f , 1.0f , -1.0f);
    glEnd();

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    xrot += 0.1;
    yrot += 0.1;
    zrot += 0.1;

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Try printing the contents of the image itself, maybe `freeimage` is having trouble reading the file?

Comment: Also, what lighting and material properties are you using?

Comment: what is the value of `texture[0]`? Is it `0` ??

Comment: Could you also post your render function? If my answer doesn't work, the problem may be found there.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things that might go wrong in your code.

My suspicion is, that you call `initGL()` prematurely, i.e without a context being available yet. You didn't show the code in question, so I can make only guesses about this.

Enabling the texturing unit is important for drawing only. You can upload texture data with the texture unit being disabled just fine. I strongly recommend you put that `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` right before your quad drawing code and nowhere else (actually you should but glEnable and glDisable calls only into drawing code, for several reasons).

Loading the texture you fail to perform several sanity checks. Also you forget to properly set pixel store parameters, but that would make your texture look distorted. Also it would make sense to return the texture ID from your load function, instead of a boolean and putting the ID into a global variable. Texuture ID 0 is reserved, so you can use that to indicate an error.

You set the filter mode though, so this is not an issue with mipmap levels not being defined.

Comment: +1 because you are right. I myself just started using OpenGL for a school project, and I thought I stumbled upon some post somewhere stating it was a necessary call, so I (naive as I am) just took it for being true.

Comment: Moving glEnable just before it renders quad had something show up. I don't have white but I can see something so its is a step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`GL_TEXTURES_2D` needs to be enabled before you create textures, so you need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` before calling `glGenTextures(1 , &texture[0]);`</strike>

Also, to enable transparency, you need to call `glEnable(GL_BLEND);`

Still this doesn't explain why it works on Ubuntu but not on Windows... I'd say give it a try and see if it helps.

EDIT:
Now you've posted your render function, 1 thing I notice is that you are not setting your rendering color.
Try calling

```
glColor4f(r,g,b,a); // r, g, b and a are float between [0,1], specifying your desired color
```

somewhere between `glLoadIdentity();` and your first `glVertex3f` call

Comment: I have enabled `GL_TEXTURES_2D` in initgl function.

Comment: As I said, you need to enable it BEFORE generating your textures, right now you are doing it afterwards.

Comment: I put it before `loadGLTextures` and it is still the same.

Comment: I have posted my render function.

Comment: I called it :glColor4f(1 , 1 , 1 , 1) nothing happens.Does this relate to the texture?

Comment: -1 because, no, you don't have to enable GL_TEXTURE_2D for texture creation. Actually all the OpenGL enable/disable states affect drawing only, but not the rest of operations.

Answer (score 0):

your texture dimensions might not be the power of two, that is 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on.

That can also cause such a problem on some hardware, generally in older.

Cheers ;)

Comment: My texture dimensions are not from the power of two.So I'll check whether the problem is from that or not as soon as possible and will tell you the results.